# How to set up limits of slice();push();splice() methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know that:

- with splice() I can add item in array
- with pop() I can delete last item in array
- with push() I can add item in array

Now I want to know how can I set up limit. For instance I want when a user clicks, he should be able to make this performance of array's methods 
`slice();push();splice()` only one or two times. How can I make it possible to use this array methods for two times?

code:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

    function myFunction() {
        fruits.push("Kiwi");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

    function myFunction() {
        fruits.pop();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you need to to manually prevent the user by a counter value, which is incremented for every set of operations or by validating the length of the array after every operation with the limit value.

Answer (score 1):

```
var limit = 2;
if (limit) {
    fruits.pop();
    limit--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this :

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="error"></p>

<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

var limit = 2;
function myFunction() {
  if(limit > 0) {
    limit = limit - 1 ;
    fruits.push("Kiwi");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
  }
  else {
    
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Your limit reached";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this , by setting a counter.

```
<script>
var pushCounter = 0;
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
    if(pushCounter<2)
    {
     fruits.push("Kiwi");
     pushCounter++;    
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just validate the length of the fruits array with limit for every operation and ignore the operation when limit reached with a alert message to user.

**JS CODE:**

```
var limit = 1;
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
   if(fruits.length === limit){
       alert('limit reached cant pop the items anymore!!!');
       return;
   }
   fruits.pop();
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}

myFunction(); //["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"];
myFunction(); //["Banana", "Orange"];
myFunction(); //["Banana"];
myFunction(); //pop operation denied
```